# Form property 'is undefined' error in some situations but not others

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox, greasemonkey

I've created the following greasemonkey script to automatically jump me past the steam age check pages:

```
// ==UserScript==
// ...
// @include     http://store.steampowered.com/agecheck/*
// ==/UserScript==

//Mini script for doing steam age checks automatically
if( document.URL.indexOf('agecheck') > -1 )
{
    var form = document.getElementById('agegate_box').getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
    form.ageDay.value = 18;
    form.ageMonth.value = 'August';
    form.ageYear.value = 1987;
    form.submit();
}
```

An example of such a page is: http://store.steampowered.com/agecheck/app/16730/. Note that this page will skip automatically to the game if you have the `store.steampowered.com` "birthtime" cookie set, so you might have to delete it first.

When this greasemonkey script is installed on Firefox 17.0 (beta) running on Windows XP, it works fine.

I then installed the script on my Windows 7 machine, which is running the latest FF (16). On this machine, the script breaks when accessing form.ageDay. The error console shows:

```
Error: form.ageDay is undefined
```

Even stranger though, is that if I simply paste my script into the Firefox Scratchpad (Shift+F4) and execute it, it works find and the form submits.

How is it possible that on XP the GM script works, and in Win7 the script works in the scratchpad, but on Win7 the script doesn't work in GM?

Yet another oddity is that on the Win7 machine, if I activate Firebug, `var form` clearly has a 'ageDay' property, but the watch expression returns undefined?

[image]

Comment: That way of accessing form elements is very old ("DOM level 0"). Maybe GM (partially?) dropped support for it? I don't know, just a guess.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GM scripts - but could they be executing before the DOM is ready? i.e. the form hasn't actually finished loading yet?

Comment: @Matt GreaseMonkey scripts are themselves executed on `DOMContentLoaded`: http://wiki.greasespot.net/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: @bfavaretto what would be the better way of accessing form elements? I'd like to give it a shot.

Comment: @Alain Not sure if it's "better", but you can give each element an `id`, then access them with `document.getElementById`. The will return a `Node` element, with the usual `value` property.

Comment: @bfavaretto Unfortunately, I don't have access to the steam store website source code to give those form elements ids. :p

Comment: Just for the sake of curiousity, what if you checked to see if `form` was undefined, and if set use `setTimeout` to retry again in X amount of seconds? Could it be this form itself is getting loaded asynchronously by steam?

Comment: @Matt tried that. Form is always defined right away. If I wait on form.ageYear becoming defined it never happens and it just loops for eternity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code doesn't work for me on either Windows XP or Windows 7. Nor should it.  GM scripts can't (normally) use named form objects like that.  See [Greasemonkey Pitfall: Named Forms and Form Elements](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.233%3a_Named_Forms_and_Form_Elements).

Use sandbox-safe (and more powerful) methods to get at those form elements.  For example, `querySelector()`.  This script works for me on the page you linked:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _delme 677
// @include     http://store.steampowered.com/agecheck/*
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

//Mini script for doing steam age checks automatically
if (/agecheck/i.test (location.pathname) ) {
    var ageForm = document.querySelector ("#agegate_box form");
    ageForm.querySelector ("[name='ageDay']").value     = 18;
    ageForm.querySelector ("[name='ageMonth']").value   = 'August';
    ageForm.querySelector ("[name='ageYear']").value    = 1987;
    ageForm.submit ();
}
```

---

Notes:

1. Firefox Scratchpad worked because it is not isolated by the GM sandbox.
2. As for why it appeared to work on Win XP, That is most likely a fluke -- it doesn't work for me on XP, and it shouldn't.

   It may be possible that for certain `@grant none` scenarios, that kind of code might work. (`@grant none` gets applied by default in many cases; see the docs.)

   Or there may have been more than one version of the script in operation, or even FF got corrupted and needed to be restarted.

   Bottom line, is don't code that way.
3. As for `but the watch expression returns undefined?`... That's just the sandbox isolation at work, and it looks the same way on XP, to me.
4. Code, like the above using `querySelector()` will work on just about every page a user might encounter, and **it certainly works within the parameters of this question**.  But it currently does not work on some *possible* HTML5 forms and some ***invalid*** HTML that some sites allegedly used to use.

   In both cases, the code mentioned in the pitfall link, that I gave above, will work, despite certain invalid HTML or bleeding-edge HTML5, proposed features.

   Specifically, this kind of code, while not as flexible as `querySelector`, will work with a wider set of scenarios (even if they are invalid HTML):

   ```
   if (/agecheck/i.test (location.pathname) ) {
       var ageForm = document.querySelector ("#agegate_box form");
       ageForm.elements.namedItem ('ageDay').value     = 18;
       ageForm.elements.namedItem ('ageMonth').value   = 'August';
       ageForm.elements.namedItem ('ageYear').value    = 1987;
       ageForm.submit ();
   }
   ```

Comment: You've done it. Thank you so much for finding the solution, the explanation, and the beautiful code. I'm only on day 4 of writing javascript so there's like 3 great new things in there for me :p

Comment: Uh...  The right way to do this is `ageForm.elements.namedItem('ageDay')`. Using `querySelector` will fail in all sorts of cases...

Comment: @BorisZbarsky, Oh really?  Name two that apply in this case.

Comment: 1) `<form id="myForm"></form><input form="myForm" name="ageDay">`

Comment: 2) `<table><form id="myForm"><tr><td><input name="ageDay"></td></tr></form></table>`

Comment: @BrockAdams And note that "this case" is a greasemonkey script that therefore needs to be able to work with all web pages, so needs to handle all cases like that.  Unless you want to have it randomly break if the page gets changed a bit, of course.

Comment: My first example is perfectly valid HTML5.  And the second example is extremely commonly used on pages.

Comment: Okay, your first example **is** valid HTML5, and you claim that the second example is common (I've never seen it).  Neither have any bearing on the OP's case/target-pages nor, I wager, on 98% of the pages that other readers will try to script.  But `.elements` ***does*** work in a wider variety of `<form>` element scenarios.  So I've amended the answer.  Sorry for not checking your snippets against an HTML5 validator before my earlier reply.  Note that I already had linked the pitfalls section, which still has the `.elements`-style workaround.

Comment: PS.  Does *any* real, commercial site use HTML5 form features -- given that only Opera has full support and IE currently has no support (until IE10)?.